# How to echo data from Blob which contain image

Tags: php, tinymce, echo

I am using TinyMCE text editor, In this editor i paste some text and image and save in database. Now i want to echo this data, want to echo image that is store in db using text editor. In Data base column type is blob.

I tried following but failed.

1. `$client_id = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(nl2br($row['test'])));`
2. `$client_id = mysql_real_escape_string($row['test']);`
3. `$client_id = nl2br($row['test']);`

Please help me how i can echo image that is store in blob by using text editor.

Than you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the base64_encoding function

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image->load()) .'" />';
```

Comment: But it contain some text also. i want to echo both text and image,

Comment: You have text and image in the same field?

Comment: Yes m using Text editor and save all data in same field

Comment: I don't really think it is possible, anyway it is another question and may be some body can help you if you ask for it. 
I would change the logic, storing separately text and image and retrieving the image as I answered